# Spring+Quartz Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR.: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We have Quartz 2.2.1 set up running from a JSF web application using Spring 4.1.3 on JBoss EAP 6.4 (we are using Quartz to schedule user submitted queries so that we can balance how much is running at once). JDK 8.

Occasionally we are seeing the following error in the log and the job is never running:

```
  16:07:02,343 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore] (scheduler_MyJob_QuartzSchedulerThread) Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR.: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because the BLOB couldn't be deserialized: null [See nested exception: java.io.EOFException]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1392) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggerFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2964) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$43.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2908) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$43.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2901) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3787) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggersFired(JobStoreSupport.java:2900) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:336) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2328) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2797) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate.getObjectFromBlob(OracleDelegate.java:139) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:860) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1385) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]
   ... 6 more
```

Here is the configuration for the scheduler:

```
       <bean id="scheduler_myJob"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
          lazy-init="false">
          <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey"
                         value="applicationContext" />
          <property name="startupDelay" value="90" />
          <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
          <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
          <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
          <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDS" />
          <property name="quartzProperties">
                 <props>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Scheduler_MyJob</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">864000000</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">
                              org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
                       </prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">
                              org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
                       </prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"> DWDATA.MY_QRTZ_</prop>  
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock">true</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">4</prop>
                       <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                 </props>
          </property>
   </bean>
```

I have tried emptying out the QUARTZ tables in the database (Oracle), and have ensured that there are no other instances of the application running against the tables (this is in our development environment where all of the developers may be running locally but against a shared database).

I have tried adding a TriggerListener and a JobListener, but this error happens before those are called (they work fine for the instances where the error does not occur).

The error does not happen every time that we submit a job, and the request will go through just fine after the error. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to it.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, so I'm hoping that someone here knows of this error and can provide a solution.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running? Maybe this will help?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789218/oracle-blob-exception-during-deployment-starting-up-war-on-wildfly8

Comment: @Brian Oracle 12.2.0.4.0 - using ojdbc 7 jar file. I will check out the other post, but does it make sense that it would only happen sometimes?

Comment: The attempt was made to craft a custom delegate but that did not work either. In order to save time, we simply have an update script run periodically to update "ERROR" states in the trigger table to be "WAITING" so that the jobs would run as expected.